# How do I make async HTTP requests using httpx (VS requests) in Python?

Tags: python, python-requests, python-asyncio, httpx

I'm new to `httpx` and `async` and I'm having trouble converting a function that calls to an external API using `requests` into an asynchronous function using `httpx`.

This is the original function:

```
import requests


def get_api_data(url: str) -> Optional[List[str]]:
    """Get the data from an API url.
    Args:
        url (str):  The API url.
    Returns:
        list: The data.
    """
    try:
        resp = requests.get(url)
        return resp.json()
    except requests.exceptions.HTTPError as errh:
        print("Http Error:", errh)
    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as errc:
        print("Error Connecting:", errc)
    except requests.exceptions.Timeout as errt:
        print("Timeout Error:", errt)
    except requests.exceptions.RequestException as err:
        print("OOps: Something Else", err)
```

and this is what I've tried:

```
import httpx


async def get_api_data(url: str) -> Optional[List[Any]]:
    """Get the data from an API url.
    Args:
        url (str):  The API url.
    Returns:
        list: The data.
    """
    try:
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            resp = await client.get(url)
            return resp.json()
    except httpx.HTTPError as errh:
        print("Http Error:", errh)
```

But I'm not sure it's a valid code and how to test it...

An example of a test before changing the function (the `requests` version); It uses `patch` to mock:

```
import pytest
import requests

from unittest.mock import patch


def test_api_http_error():
    with patch('app.internal.world_clock.requests.get', side_effect=requests.exceptions.HTTPError):
        assert not get_api_data(TIMEZONES_BASE_URL)
```

I spent a lot of hours trying to figure this out, so if you have any suggestions for how to make this conversion properly and how to test it - I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Definitely, a confusion about catching exceptions, e.g. `HttpError` is the base for the rest, look at the hierarchy [here](https://www.python-httpx.org/exceptions/) and rearrange them accordingly

Comment: The summary doesn't make it clear what is your actual question. The code appears correct and you can test it by passing it an external URL to fetch - e.g. `print(asyncio.run(get_api_data(<some url>)))`. You could also extend the same approach to unit tests. What concrete problem are you facing?

Answer (score 1):

Your function looks fine. Are you running your async function? I had that issue when I first tried using it to replace requests in my project. Instead of just calling it like: `results = async_funtion(parameter)`
It needed to be:
`results = asyncio.run(async_funtion(parameter))`
In the first example you are just creating a coroutine object, the second actually runs it.